# Launch Screen image doesn't display Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to add image in Launch screen (Logo) in storyboard but doesn't display
I Followed Xamarin documentation but no way .. when i drag and drop image and set image to image set which i added in assets nothing changed 
Launch screen works fine if i change background color or something like that

```
 Note : In story board when i try to select image view image .. it open
 explorer didn't make me choose from image set
```

[image]

how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you configured info.plist?

Comment: yes but doesn't work ,, i posted a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i follow this it works fine

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/319294/xamarinios-cant-select-image-asset-for-image-view.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Asset catalogs in the LaunchScreen.storyboard, it is not necessary to name the Asset file as LaunchImages. Click the add button at the left top of this window, you will get an Asset file named Images. You can rename it then add three sizes of images(1x, 2x, 3x), after doing that this image can be used adapting all apple phone devices.

Then click save all button at the top window or use Ctrl + Shift + s to save this behavior. At last drag and drop down an Image view control on the LaunchScreen.storyboard, you will find this image called the Asset file's name instead of the images' original name in the image view's property window's image list.

Comment: i did what you said but no name is shown and when i click drop down in image view properties it open windows explorer